# "Is there still any confusion?" Or "Is there any confusion still?"

Tags: american-english

I know after verb we can use "still". But what about interrogative sentences?

Comment: As a standalone sentence, neither sounds too natural, though I'm sure context will make the first variant sound better. Neither is wrong per se, but 'Is there still any confusion about X?' would be more idiomatic, and 'Is there any confusion still about X?' would sound like awkward spoken phrasing. // Google Ngrams seem to indicate that all variants are rare. A raw Google search shows that 'is there still some milk?' is not nearly as rare as 'is there some milk still?'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the most complete answer, but in this case, as a native English speaker, I would prefer the first.

I think the general rule in normal writing and speech is that an adverb is placed after the verb and the subject. The subject in this example ("there") is placed after the verb, so the adverb would go after that, as you wrote in your first example.

The only time that an adverb should be placed at the end is if you want to emphasise it. Both ways are completely correct, but the first is more common.